# Self Referencing table in Procedure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have few procedures on my local SQL server.I want to move to Azure Server.

Now the thing is I have 3 databases on each server.Some procedure refers table from other database.I also found that Self Referencing was also done in some procedures.

The procedure compiled successfully but my question is ,is it feasible to keep self reference database tables on Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-database queries are possible on Azure SQL. [Azure SQL Database elastic query overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview)

> The elastic query feature (in preview) enables you to run a Transact-SQL query that spans multiple databases in Azure SQL Database. It allows you to perform cross-database queries to access remote tables, and to connect Microsoft and third party tools (Excel, PowerBI, Tableau, etc.) to query across data tiers with multiple databases.
>
> **Azure SQL Database**
>
> Query across Azure SQL databases completely in T-SQL. This allows for read-only querying of remote databases. **This provides an option for current on-premises SQL Server customers to migrate applications using three- and four-part names or linked server to SQL DB.**
>
> ...
>
> Customer scenarios for elastic query are characterized by the following topologies:
>
> **Vertical partitioning** - Cross-database queries (Topology 1): The data is partitioned vertically between a number of databases in a data tier. Typically, different sets of tables reside on different databases. That means that the schema is different on different databases. For instance, all tables for inventory are on one database while all accounting-related tables are on a second database. Common use cases with this topology require one to query across or to compile reports across tables in several databases.